# Can't use "i" hotkey in pose mode

Tags: animation, bones

I'm not sure what exactly happened.  But I was working on creating a walk cycle for a rig and I guess I mistyped something and now I cant use the insert keyframe hotkey whilst in pose mode.  I can use it in object mode, and I can still use the manual "insert pose" buttons in rig mode, but the i hotkey refuses to work when any bones in pose mode are selected.

Comment: What does *"refuses to work"* mean? What happens when you press it?

Comment: Nothing happens, the keyframe selection window just it won't show up.  Like the key doesn't register or something like that.